# How to solve this double sum?

Tags: summation

I need help with a double sum. I would like to express the following as one sum only:
$$\sum\limits_{T=t}^{\infty} \beta^{T-t} \sum\limits_{S=t}^{T-1}(x_S-y_{S+1})$$.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why do you expect it to be expressed as a single sum?

Answer (score 2):

To make things easier, let's consider
$$
\sum_{T=t}^\infty \beta^{T-t}\sum_{S=t}^{T-1}x_S.
$$
Now, let's consider reversing the order of summation, 
$$
\sum_S x_S\sum_T\beta^{T-t}.
$$
Now, as $T$ gets large in the original sum, $S$ can also get large, so the indices on the outer summation is
$$
\sum_{S=t}^\infty x_S\sum_T\beta^{T-t}.
$$
Now, we have to figure out which terms in the original sum have the term $x_S$.  This only happens when $S\leq T-1$, or $T\geq S+1$.  Therefore, the second sum is
$$
\sum_{S=t}^\infty x_S\sum_{T=S+1}^\infty \beta^{T-t}.
$$
Now, the inner sum is a geometric sum, so you can find an explicit formula for it.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, I get: $$\frac{1}{1-\beta}\sum\limits_{T=t}^{\infty}(x_T-y_{T+1})$$ right?

Comment: The geometric sum doesn't start at $0$.  It changes for each $S$.

Comment: I forgot one thing, sorry. Should it be $$\frac{1}{1-\beta}\sum\limits_{T=t}^{\infty}\beta^{T-t}(x_t-y_{T+1})?$$

Comment: Your exponent on $\beta$ might be off by $1$ since the geometric series should start at $0$.

Comment: Yes, I was not sure about this. Thank you!